# Automatic data summarization with text

Tags: text-generation

I would like to automate periodic report writing based on data. Given one/some data tables, the machine should output texts like `Stock A rose by 10% this year and hit 5 year high on 2019-12-01`, or `we made a large profit in sector B`.

I can find the subject *automatic text summarization*, but seems it's about reading text and shorten it to its key sentences. Not exactly data summarization.

Could someone recommend some book/paper/video/MOOC on *text generation based on data*?

Answer (score 0):

Then check out this tutorial [generative/abstractive](https://medium.com/intel-student-ambassadors/diving-into-abstractive-text-summarization-part-1-e8570d370021) text summarization.